# Error with facebook login button javasdk

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

i use that code to generate access token with facebook jssdk and use pre to insert the generated code to the same file, but it dont works

```
       <fb:login-button scope="offline_access, manage_pages">Grant offline_access</fb:login-button>
<h1>Access Token:</h1>
<pre id="access-token"></pre>

<script>
var
  pre         = document.getElementById('access-token'),
  showSession = function(response) {
    var html = 'Not Connected';
    if (response.authResponse) {
      html = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    }
    pre.innerHTML = html;
  };
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  showSession(response);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', showSession);
});
</script>
```

Also word "Not Connected: didn't show in the page

Comment: Mind you giving us your whole code?

Comment: no minds, but the error i think it is not related to the hole code now 
its about <script></script> code included in the question